# Парсинг таблицы с помощью selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Есть сайт в котором список товаров представлен в виде таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<table class="productListing table table-striped" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0"><tbody><tr><td width="70" class="prod_info12 td_img"><div class="left"><a href="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/kabel-ciphrovogo-usilitelja-gazer-ma082-hyundaikia-p-15862.html?osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56" id="r_img_15862"><img src="http://caralarm.com.ua/images/sma_17673.jpg" height="70" border="0" alt="Кабель цифрового усилителя Gazer MA082 (Hyundai/Kia)" title="Кабель цифрового усилителя Gazer MA082 (Hyundai/Kia)"></a></div></td><td width="170" class="prod_info12"><div class="clear"></div><span class="prod_info_list_name"><a href="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/kabel-ciphrovogo-usilitelja-gazer-ma082-hyundaikia-p-15862.html?osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56">Кабель цифрового усилителя Gazer MA082 (Hyundai/Kia)</a></span><br><span class="style36">Код: 17673</span></td><td class="prod_info12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
<span class="prod_info11">
Кабель для подключения к цифровому усилителю автомобилей Hyundai
</span>
</td><td width="95" class="prod_info12"> <span class="style24"><s>$1.65</s></span> <span class="style24">$1.63 </span><br><span class="style23_font">52 грн</span><span class="style23" style="display: block;font-size: 12px;color: blue;white-space: nowrap;">Мин. р. 63 грн</span></td><td width="130" class="prod_info12"><div class="style29"><span class="style36">Нет в наличии</span><br><input class="style26" type="text" name="cart_quantity" id="count15862" maxlength="3" size="1" value="1">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.href ='two_week_info.php?idp=15862&amp;cnt='+document.getElementById('count15862').value;$(this).click();">
<img src="http://caralarm.com.ua/images//zakaz32.jpg" class="style27"></a></div></td></tr><tr><td width="70" class="prod_info12 td_img"><div class="left"><a href="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/perehodnik-rcaj25-gazer-ca25r-p-19126.html?osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56" id="r_img_19126"><img src="http://caralarm.com.ua/images/" height="70" border="0" alt="Переходник RCA-J2,5&quot; Gazer CA25R" title="Переходник RCA-J2,5&quot; Gazer CA25R"></a></div></td><td width="170" class="prod_info12"><div class="clear"></div><span class="prod_info_list_name"><a href="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/perehodnik-rcaj25-gazer-ca25r-p-19126.html?osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56">Переходник RCA-J2,5" Gazer CA25R</a></span><br><span class="style36">Код: 20490</span></td><td class="prod_info12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
<span class="prod_info11">
Переходник RCA-J2,5"" для подключения камеры заднего вида Gazer к монитору или навигатору
Переходник RCA - Jack 2,5"" для подключения камеры заднего ...
</span>
</td><td width="95" class="prod_info12"> <span class="style24"><s>$1.68</s></span> <span class="style24">$1.66 </span><br><span class="style23_font">53 грн</span><span class="style23" style="display: block;font-size: 12px;color: blue;white-space: nowrap;">Мин. р. 82 грн</span></td><td width="130" class="prod_info12"><form name="cart_quantity" action="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/index.php?action=add_product&amp;keywords=Gazer&amp;osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56" method="post" onsubmit="doAddProduct(this); return false;">
<div class="prod_col_buy" id="r_buy19126"><span class="style25">В наличии</span><br><input class="style26" type="text" name="cart_quantity" maxlength="3" size="1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="products_id" value="19126">
<a href="#" class="wishlist_btn" data-id="19126" data-action="add" title="Добавить в закладки"></a>
<input type="image" src="templates/from_osc_sma/images/buttons/russian/shop_buy.jpg" border="0" alt="Добавить в Корзину" title=" Добавить в Корзину " class="style28"></div>
</form></td></tr><tr><td width="70" class="prod_info12 td_img"><div class="left"><a href="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/perehodnik-rcaj35-gazer-ca35r-p-19127.html?osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56" id="r_img_19127"><img src="http://caralarm.com.ua/images/" height="70" border="0" alt="Переходник RCA-J3,5&quot; Gazer CA35R" title="Переходник RCA-J3,5&quot; Gazer CA35R"></a></div></td><td width="170" class="prod_info12"><div class="clear"></div><span class="prod_info_list_name"><a href="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/perehodnik-rcaj35-gazer-ca35r-p-19127.html?osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56">Переходник RCA-J3,5" Gazer CA35R</a></span><br><span class="style36">Код: 20491</span></td><td class="prod_info12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
<span class="prod_info11">
Переходник RCA-J3,5"" для подключения камеры заднего вида Gazer к монитору или навигатору
Переходник RCA - Jack 3,5"" для подключения камеры заднего ...
</span>
</td><td width="95" class="prod_info12"> <span class="style24"><s>$1.68</s></span> <span class="style24">$1.66 </span><br><span class="style23_font">53 грн</span><span class="style23" style="display: block;font-size: 12px;color: blue;white-space: nowrap;">Мин. р. 82 грн</span></td><td width="130" class="prod_info12"><div class="style29"><span class="style36">Нет в наличии</span><br><input class="style26" type="text" name="cart_quantity" id="count19127" maxlength="3" size="1" value="1">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.href ='two_week_info.php?idp=19127&amp;cnt='+document.getElementById('count19127').value;$(this).click();">
<img src="http://caralarm.com.ua/images//zakaz32.jpg" class="style27"></a></div></td></tr><tr><td width="70" class="prod_info12 td_img"><div class="left"><a href="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/kreplenie-dlja-kamery-gazer-cc-p-27492.html?osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56" id="r_img_27492"><img src="http://caralarm.com.ua/images/sma_dsfc_1219.jpg" height="70" border="0" alt="Крепление для камеры Gazer CC" title="Крепление для камеры Gazer CC"></a></div></td><td width="170" class="prod_info12"><div class="clear"></div><span class="prod_info_list_name"><a href="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/kreplenie-dlja-kamery-gazer-cc-p-27492.html?osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56">Крепление для камеры Gazer CC</a></span><br><span class="style36">Код: 20026</span></td><td class="prod_info12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
<span class="prod_info11">
Крепление для камеры Gazer CС. Тип крепления - бабочка
</span>
</td><td width="95" class="prod_info12"><span class="style24">$2 </span><br><span class="style23_font">64 грн</span>&nbsp;</td><td width="130" class="prod_info12"><form name="cart_quantity" action="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/index.php?action=add_product&amp;keywords=Gazer&amp;osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56" method="post" onsubmit="doAddProduct(this); return false;">
<div class="prod_col_buy" id="r_buy27492"><span class="style25">В наличии</span><br><input class="style26" type="text" name="cart_quantity" maxlength="3" size="1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="products_id" value="27492">
<a href="#" class="wishlist_btn" data-id="27492" data-action="add" title="Добавить в закладки"></a>
<input type="image" src="templates/from_osc_sma/images/buttons/russian/shop_buy.jpg" border="0" alt="Добавить в Корзину" title=" Добавить в Корзину " class="style28"></div>
</form></td></tr><tr><td width="70" class="prod_info12 td_img"><div class="left"><a href="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/perehodnik-usb-razyoma-gazer-am125-vwskodaseat-p-15859.html?osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56" id="r_img_15859"><img src="http://caralarm.com.ua/images/sma_17665091115.jpg" height="70" border="0" alt="Переходник USB разъёма Gazer AM125 (VW/Skoda/Seat)" title="Переходник USB разъёма Gazer AM125 (VW/Skoda/Seat)"></a></div></td><td width="170" class="prod_info12"><div class="clear"></div><span class="prod_info_list_name"><a href="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/perehodnik-usb-razyoma-gazer-am125-vwskodaseat-p-15859.html?osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56">Переходник USB разъёма Gazer AM125 (VW/Skoda/Seat)</a></span><br><span class="style36">Код: 17665</span></td><td class="prod_info12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
<span class="prod_info11">
Переходник для штатного USB разъема автомобилей VW/Skoda/Seat
</span>
</td><td width="95" class="prod_info12"> <span class="style24"><s>$3.3</s></span> <span class="style24">$3.25 </span><br><span class="style23_font">104 грн</span><span class="style23" style="display: block;font-size: 12px;color: blue;white-space: nowrap;">Мин. р. 136 грн</span></td><td width="130" class="prod_info12"><div class="style29"><span class="style36">Нет в наличии</span><br><input class="style26" type="text" name="cart_quantity" id="count15859" maxlength="3" size="1" value="1">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.href ='two_week_info.php?idp=15859&amp;cnt='+document.getElementById('count15859').value;$(this).click();">
<img src="http://caralarm.com.ua/images//zakaz32.jpg" class="style27"></a></div></td></tr><tr><td width="70" class="prod_info12 td_img"><div class="left"><a href="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/akkumuljator-gazer-ab302-p-12681.html?osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56" id="r_img_12681"><img src="http://caralarm.com.ua/images/akkym_gazer_115-sss.jpg" height="70" border="0" alt="Аккумулятор Gazer AB302" title="Аккумулятор Gazer AB302"></a></div></td><td width="170" class="prod_info12"><div class="clear"></div><span class="prod_info_list_name"><a href="https://m.caralarm.com.ua/akkumuljator-gazer-ab302-p-12681.html?osCsid=fafc1955938031b9d6e0b0db91480f56">Аккумулятор Gazer AB302</a></span><br><span class="style36">Код: 14230</span></td><td class="prod_info12 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
<span class="prod_info11">
Аккумулятор к видеорегистратоу Gazer F115
</span>
</td><td width="95" class="prod_info12"> <span class="style24"><s>$4.13</s></span> <span class="style24">$4.06 </span><br><span class="style23_font">130 грн</span><span class="style23" style="display: block;font-size: 12px;color: blue;white-space: nowrap;">Мин. р. 174 грн</span></td><td width="130" class="prod_info12"><div class="style29"><span class="style36">Нет в наличии</span><br><input class="style26" type="text" name="cart_quantity" id="count12681" maxlength="3" size="1" value="1">
</tr></tbody></table>
```

И мне нужно вывести данные в виде "Имя, цена, наличие", довольно простой обычный парсинг сайта, но проблема в том что при попытке перебирать и выводить к примеру наименование товара, выводится только 1 элемент (Кабель цифрового усилителя Gazer MA082), и дальше цикл не продвигается, как сделать так что перебирало все элементы?

Вот пример моего кода:

```py
def parse(url: str) -> List[Tuple[str, str, str]]:
     for item_el in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'prod_info12'):

                name = item_el.find_element_by_xpath('prod_info_list_name').text
                
                try:
                    nal = item_el.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="block"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/span').text                    
                except:
                    nal = 'Не задано'     
                       

                try:
                    price = item_el.find_element_by_class_name('display: block;font-size: 12px;color: blue;white-space: nowrap;').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    price = '-'
```

И вот что выводит:

```
('Кабель цифрового усилителя Gazer MA082 (Hyundai/Kia)', '-', 'Нет в наличии')
('Кабель цифрового усилителя Gazer MA082 (Hyundai/Kia)', '-', 'Нет в наличии')
('Кабель цифрового усилителя Gazer MA082 (Hyundai/Kia)', '-', 'Нет в наличии')
('Кабель цифрового усилителя Gazer MA082 (Hyundai/Kia)', '-', 'Нет в наличии')
('Кабель цифрового усилителя Gazer MA082 (Hyundai/Kia)', '-', 'Нет в наличии')
('Кабель цифрового усилителя Gazer MA082 (Hyundai/Kia)', '-', 'Нет в наличии')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение вопроса было довольно простым, если посмотреть на структуру Xpath таблицы, то можно увидеть следующее:

`//*[@id="block"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[x]/td[x]/span[1]/a`, где `tr` - это строка, а  `td` - это столбец

На странице отображается ровно 30 товаров, поэтому подставляя значения нужной нам ячейки мы можем спокойно забирать с нее данные, итоговый код для того что бы вытянуть name выглядит вот так:

```
 for item_el in range(1,30):

                name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="block"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[{item_el}]/td[2]/span[1]/a').text
                
                print(name)
```

Вывод:

```
Кабель цифрового усилителя Gazer MA082 (Hyundai/Kia)
Переходник RCA-J2,5" Gazer CA25R
Переходник RCA-J3,5" Gazer CA35R
Крепление для камеры Gazer CC
Переходник USB разъёма Gazer AM125 (VW/Skoda/Seat)
Аккумулятор Gazer AB302
Аккумулятор Gazer AB303
Рамка переходная Gazer AM101
Рамка переходная Gazer AM501
Крепление к видеокамере Gazer CAH01 (HYUNDAI)
Крепление к видеокамере Gazer CALF2 (LAND ROVER)
Крепление к камере задего вида Gazer CA577 (RENAULT)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA813 (Chery)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA006-L (VOLVO)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA00A (Renault)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA010-L (LEXUS)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA021 (Toyota)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA022 (MITSUBISHI)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA028-L (Gelly)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA031 (Toyota)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA032 (Opel)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA033-L (LEXUS)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA060 (TOYOTA)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA097 (Geely)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA099-L (Mitsubishi)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA0A3 (CITROEN)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA0F0-L (Citroen/Peugeot)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA0G3-L (Citroen/Peugeot)
Крепление к камере заднего вида Gazer CA0G9 (PEUGEOUT/CITROEN)
```